# kivy adding widget without kivy language

Tags: python, widget, kivy

I wanted to make a small game with an enemy-widget that disappears when you click on it.
A added the Enemy to an widget using kivy-language and it worked fine, but I wanted to add multiple enemys and I don't want to add more and more Enemys, so I wanted to use the add_widget command to andd the enemy witget to the place widget, but I got the Error:

```
 TypeError: unbound method add_widget() must be called with place instance as first argument (got WidgetMetaclass instance instead)
```

Here is the sourcecode:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.animation import Animation

class place(Widget):
    pass
class Enemy(Widget):
    velocity = NumericProperty(1)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Enemy, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.Update, 1/60.)
    def Update(self, *args):
        self.x -= self.velocity
        if self.x < 1:
            self.velocity = 0
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print 'es geht'
            self.velocity = 0
            self.parent.remove_widget(self)


ROOT = Builder.load_string('''
FloatLayout:
    Button:
        text: 'Go Back'
        size_hint: 0.3, 0.1
        pos_hint: {"x": 0, 'y':0}
    place:
<place>:
    Enemy:
        pos: 400, 100
<Enemy>:
    Image:
        pos: root.pos
        id: myimage
        source: 'enemy.png'

''')

class Caption(App):
    def build(self):
        place.add_widget(Enemy)
        return ROOT
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Caption().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple problems with your code.  First the python problem:

The error you are getting is telling you that you are trying to call in *instance method* on a class (as opposed to an object of that class).

```
place.add_widget(Enemy)
```

`place` is a class (or "type" if you prefer, and it might be helpful to name it Place to follow a constistent naming convention), and you need an object of type 'place' to call .add_widget on.  Similarly, `Enemy` is a class, not an object, so you need to create a new object of type `Enemy`:

```
obj.add_widget(Enemy(pos=(400,300))
```

Where obj is an *instance* of place, and Enemy() creates an *instance* of enemy.

Now the kivy problem:

You can't access a widget in kv from python by it's name.  You have to tag it with an id and then reference that id:

```
ROOT = Builder.load_string('''
FloatLayout:
    Button:
        text: 'Go Back'
        size_hint: 0.3, 0.1
        pos_hint: {"x": 0, 'y':0}
    place:
        id: place
<place>:
    Enemy:
        pos: 400, 100
<Enemy>:
    Image:
        pos: root.pos
        id: myimage
        source: 'enemy.png'

''')

class Caption(App):
    def build(self):
        obj = ROOT.ids.place
        obj.add_widget(Enemy(pos=(400,300)))
        return ROOT
```

[See here for more info](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#accessing-widgets-defined-inside-kv-lang-in-your-python-code)

Comment: Thank you. I did this and get the error error massage:   File "teil.py", line 52
    return ROOT
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: oops, missing a right paren on the previous line, fixed.

Comment: thanks, it worked, but ehat do I do if I have an screen manager?

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean, a screen manager is another container widget and the same rules apply.  note if your screens have *their own* separate rules, ids are only available to the root of their own rule.  That means you'd have to give the screen you want to access an id then access its internal id in a nested fashion like: ```root.ids.id_of_screen.ids.id_of_widget_on_screen```